# Close a popup window by clicking on a button on the parent page

Tags: jquery

I need to close a popup window when a button is clicked on the parent page.

The code I am working with is:

```
var targetWin = null;

function PopupCenter(URL, title,w,h) {

var URL
var w
var h

w = 1150;
h = 800;

URL = 'http://www.google.co.uk';


var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);

targetWin = window.open (URL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}  

$("#closeout").click(function(){
    targetWin.close();
});
```

The button on the parent page:

```
<div id="closeout">
  <a href="crewint.php">
    <img src="../images/logout.png" width="97" height="70" border="0" />
  </a>
</div>
```

I have tried a number a ways after reading other posts but I must be doing someting wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you declaring `out` as an object anywhere? You can't just do `element_id.onclick`, you have to do something like `var myElement = document.getElementById("element_id");` - additionally, I believe `out` is a reserved word.

Comment: @Santi Hi, I have change the code and the name of the div, but still no joy. see new code.

Comment: You're declaring `targetWin` within the scope of the function, and so it cannot be accessed from outside of it. Before your function, add `var targetWin = null;` so that we declare the variable in the global context, and drop the `var` portion from within your function. That line within the function should now just read `targetWin = window.open(...)`. See if this resolves anything.

Comment: @Santi I made the code changes (see new code) but still no joy. I click the button on the parent, the parent logs off and closes, but the popup window remains on screen.

Comment: @Santi I have run the script in the Chrome debugger and there are no errors.

Comment: If you temporarily change the `href` in your `<a>` to just `<a href="#">`, does that work? Perhaps the page redirection is happening before hitting your `window.close`.

Comment: @Santi I made the change < href='#'>. That did not work, I click on the close button on the parent page and the popup window just moves behind the parent.

Comment: Hi all, Is there a way of doing this, if not can someone point me to another solution. Many thanks.